# K-theory of $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

can anyone give some reference of K-theory and K-homology of $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$, both $K_0$ and $K_1$.

PS: also posted in stackexchange

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889706/k-theory-of-mathbbrp-infty --- Please don't post simultaneously in MO and MSE.

Comment: yes, sorry for that. But would really like to get some hint.

Comment: J.F. Adams, *Vector fields on spheres.* Ann. of Math. (2) 75 1962 603–632. See Theorem 7.3 there.